# Установить младший нулевой бит в 1

Tags: javascript

мое задание звучит так: Дано число, результатом является данное значение x, у которого младший нулевой бит установлен в 1.
Я не могу разобраться, что имеется ввиду под "нулевым" битом. Например 100000......00011. Есть порядок заполнения биг ендиан. Тогда заполняется слева направо, как мы пишем. И младший бит получается 1 слева? Как я могу выполнить свое задание? Подойдет ли такой код?
1 x |= (1 << 0)
`

Answer (score 1):

Младший нулевой бит в числе

```
 100000......00011
               ^  вот он
```

и не зависит от ендианности хранения.

Как его найти? Если без битовых трюков - то, например, сделать маску `m = 1<<k` и проверять

```
x & k
```

проходя значения k от нуля до разрядности числа (32, 64).

Как получился ноль - всё, нашли, можно установить данный бит в единицу

```
x |= m
```

Если использовать знания о битовой арифметике - т.н. битовые трюки:

Если у нас в младших разрядах есть серия единиц, предваряемая нулём, то при увеличении числа на единицу последовательно выполняется перенос, так что `011..11` превращается в `111..11`. Выполнив побитовое ИЛИ с начальным числом, мы установим тот самый нужный бит, а остальные не изменятся

```
    v вот этот хотим установить в 1
  100111
 +     1
  101000 
| 100111
  101111
```

Comment: А с битовыми трюками вроде просто `x | (x ^ (x + 1))`

Comment: @Alexey Ten Вроде даже ксора не надо `x | (x + 1)`     10011+1=10100 | 10011 = 10111. Я просто засомневался, нужно ли это автору.

Comment: точно, что-то я перестарался :)